# time() is counting down instead of counting upwards

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a lastlogin function which my gaming server saves (Unix), happily that works but instead of my time script counting up, it's going down and also goes to minus eventually.

```
$last = $row['lastlogin'] - time();
    $month = round($last / 2629743);
    $days = round($last / 86400);
    $hours = round($last / 3600);
    $mins = round($last / 60);
    if($last > (2629743 * 25)) echo "<font color='red'>Very long ago</font>";
    else if($last > 2629743) echo "$month Months ago";
    else if($last > 86400) echo "$days days ago";
    else if($last > 3600) echo "$hours Hours";
    else if($last > 60) echo "$mins Mins";
    else if($last > 1) echo "$last Secs";
```

If anyone could help me, please answer (:

Comment: time() will be a bigger number than $row['lastLogin'].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$last = time() - $row['lastlogin'];
```

I think is this...

Comment: Nice :) Just remember that time() gives you the current time... so you  always deduct any other time that is in the past from it, and not the opposite.